# How to use the XML Serializer to read xml data from a string?

Tags: c#, xml, string, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm following this guide (most detailed I've found so far):
http://blog.allanglen.com/2009/09/quickly-generate-c-data-objects-from-xml

But at "Step 4: Reading the XML File" I bump into a problem, I dont fetch my XML-data from a file, I get it as a string from a database.

Im new to C# and XML and I cant figure out how to make it work from step 4 with a string!

I'm using:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(new StringReader(dbString));
```

Where dbString is the string from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [LoadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method:

```
string xml = ... go and fetch XML from your db
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Also note that while [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) is not yet deprecated, [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) is the preferred  way to work with in-memory XML documents starting from .NET 3.5 and higher:

```
string xml = ... go and fetch XML from your db
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

---

UPDATE:

Sorry, I haven't actually looked at the blog post you have linked. I was mislead by the code snippet you posted in your question which actually has nothing to do with what's done in step 4 in the aforementioned article and what you are asking about. You seem to be trying to deserialize an XML string into an object. You could use a StringReader for that:

```
string xml = ... go and fetch XML from your db
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(catalog));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
     catalog catalog = (catalog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Thats what Im using, as stated in my first post. But how do I apply that at step 4 and the steps after?

Comment: Thank you! Will implement it and try tomorrow!

Comment: what if I have the xml generated as a string? which object can I use to deserialize? thanks

Comment: @Saher, please read my answer once again. It's exactly what the final code snippet illustrates -> deserializing a string that represents an XML document to an instance of a class.

Comment: I understand that Thanks but the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx doesn't show that Deserialize takes a StringReader at all.

Comment: never mind. StringReader is a subclass of TextReader. Thanks a lot.